# docker-compose.yml, network must be a mapping, not an array

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

Not sure how the yaml indentation works. Getting an error while defining an external network for the app to communicate

`./docker-compose.yml', network must be a mapping, not an array`

```
    version : '3'

    services:
       zmq_sub:
         image: zmq_sub
       zmq_pub:
         image: zmq_pub
         depends_on:
           - zmq_sub 

    networks:
       - zmq_network:
         external: true
```

Answer (score 6):

Mind the difference in syntax between the stanzas for each container, versus the listing of volumes and networks at the end:

```
<...snip...>
    volumes:
      - "database-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data"    ## <---- dash !
    networks:
      - foo        ### <---- dash!
      - private    ### <----- dash!
volumes:
  foovol:      # NO dash!
  barvol:     # NO dash!
networks:
  dntp:       # NO dash!
  private:    # NO dash!
```

Answer (score 3):

```
version : '3'

services:
   zmq_sub:
     image: zmq_sub
   zmq_pub:
     image: zmq_pub
     depends_on:
       - zmq_sub 

networks:
    zmq_network:
     external: true
```

It is expecting a key:value pair, but you have added a dash before zmq_network. So,removing it might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  my_app:
    image: some_image
    networks:
      - ingress

networks:
  ingress:
    name: existing_docker_network
    external: true
```

Or using default stack network name

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  my_app:
    image: some_image

networks:
  default:
    name: existing_docker_network
    external: true
```

It seems to me that you are using old docker-compose format (~2) for new version (3)